mfc worker thread needs to wake UI to run multiple functions
My UI creates a file extracts the data into a global vector and closes the file. The UI then runs a worker thread and becomes idle waiting for user or worker actions. The worker thread works on the data from the UI then does PostMessage to signify it is done. The UI's ONMESSAGE handler DOES get the message, then calls a function to write the modified data back to the file (re-opening it as modeCreate). The function gets control (a debug MessageBox gets displayed) and the open is attempted.  At that point, I get an exception. In debug mode, I can see that all pointers seem valid and the file appears to have a valid handle.
Tried to insert debug messages to track values. The function that contains the "open" call was originally inside the worker-thread and failed there. Now it is being called from the message handler and still failing.

What kind of exception are you getting? Which function throws the exception? Can't you catch it? You will get an exception (or error), if you try to "reopen" a file in modeCreate mode, if the file is open by another, or even the same application, ie if it wasn't previously closed. Easy test: Can you rename the file (from the Explorer) at the point where it is about to be overwritten? (when that debug message-box is displayed).

The exception occurs AFTER the message handler calls the function that will re-open the file. The file WAS closed before the worker thread is started. I'll try your test tomorrow.

I added the try-catch, but it didn't trap, so I looked more closely at the error message. It said a debug assertion failed in Windows/system32/mfc140d.dll/filecore.cpp line 179. So I found the filecore.cpp program and it says the file has an open handle, so I closed the file from inside the failing function and the open succeeded. It turns out that for the case when the file has 0 length (before my exception), when I originally opened it, I had not closed it (even though it was empty). Clearly user error. Thanks a bunch for getting me to delve deeper into the error message.
